# Typical ReactJS workflow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I am new to [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) and I am trying to understand the basic workflow of the library, together with [React Router](http://reacttraining.com/react-router/), no Redux. It has a relatively fast learning curve, but I am facing several problems that I would not if I understood well its underlying mechanics...

The problem I am facing is very common, I think, so I hope anyone can help me out. The situation is as follows:

- I have a very simple **component** class which shows a datatable (using the magnificent plugin [Datatables](https://datatables.net/)).
- Data is retrieved using an AJAX call to a remote API.
- The problem is that **the retrieved data contains information used to compose some links that I need**.

Let me show you the code and comment it step by step:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    /* Constructor, so far so good */
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /* componentDidMount method: it initialises the Datatable and 
       retrieves the data from the remote API (through an AJAX call).
       But how to compose <Link> components from here with the 
       retrieved information?? 
    */
    componentDidMount() {

        $('#table').DataTable({
            ...,
            ajax: {
                url: "url://toMyAPI",
            },
            columns: [
                { 
                    data: "id", 
                    render: ( data, type, full, meta ) => {
                    ...
                    }
                }
            ],
            ....
         });
    }

    /* render method: written in JSX. In here, I usually put the 
       <Link to={...}></Link> components to create my anchors within
       the webapp using React-Router. But now, I have to compose those
       links with the information retrieved from the componentDidMount 
       method, which DOES NOT lets me write JSX anymore... 
       That is the problem. 
    */
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table id="table" className="table table-striped width="100%"></table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance ;)

Comment: oh good lord mixing jquery and react... what are you doing m8 ?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery and React. There is no good reason to do so and it will only cause you headaches. Pick one or the other and stick to it. I promise that there is a way you can accomplish everything you're trying to do with pure React. Perhaps you could elaborate on *what* you're trying to do, your desired result, and we can go from there. If you're simply trying to render a table nicely there are React libraries for that, or you could make your own...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just using jQuery for a few things like AJAX calls... Nothing serious. The problem here is not jQuery, but the impossibility if writing JSX to compose <Link> components inside componentDidMount... Can you please help me with that?

Comment: A professional React-using website (or really any website in 2017) isn't going to be using jQuery anywhere. In addition, it's an anti-pattern to fetch data inside of your components to manipulate them in this way. You want to emit actions/events that will initiate network requests elsewhere and have the state changes resulting from those flow top-down through your app.

Comment: Ok, thank you all. As I said in my question, I am  just learning React and I am aware that I don't know exactly how it works behind the scenes.

Comment: And because of that, I wrote this question. I am aware that I have to respect the React pattern to benefit from all its advantages. So I was just asking how to do it from what I had. Just learning. I will try to put your advices into practice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React and jQuery together get pretty unwieldy pretty fast. If I understand what you're trying to do I'd recommend making an API call in your componentDidMount() and when the promise resolves setting the state. Then build out your table in JSX rather than using Datatables.

Something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link { from 'react-router';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  /* Constructor, so far so good */
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataset: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    apiCall().then(res => {
      this.setState({ dataset: res }); // or however your data is formatted
    });
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <div>
            <table id="table" className="table table-striped width="100%">
               <tbody>
                  {this.state.dataset.map((row, I) => {
                     <tr>
                        <td>{row.name}</td>
                        <td><Link to={row.href}>{row.detail}</Link></td>
                     </tr>
                  })}
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I'm not sure exactly how your data is formed, but something like that might work well.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but what if I need the extra capabilities of Datatables in terms of sorting, searching, etc.? I really need to use the library for those... What would be the best approach then?

Comment: You could look at this React Table library. https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme.  Or, you could use something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) to filter and search the component state.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I will have to put my world upside down :S

Answer (score -1):

import React from 'react';
import dt from './../../../from your path/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

```
/* Constructor, so far so good */
constructor() {
    super();
}

componentDidMount() {

   let table = $('#table').DataTable({
        ...,
        ajax: {
            url: "url://toMyAPI",
            dom:"B"
        },
        columns: [
            { 
                data: "id", 
                render: ( data, type, full, meta ) => {
                ...
                }
            }
        ],
        ....
     });
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table id="table" className="table table-striped width="100%"></table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}